# Parsing an .htaccess File With PHP

Tags: php, parsing, zend-framework, .htaccess, pear

I am using the Zend Framework, and I use the `.htaccess` for some settings.  I am now writing command line scripts for scheduling (e.g. cron).  Command line scripts don't look at the `.htaccess` file because they're not served up by Apache.  I would like to parse the `.htaccess` with my script to retrieve some settings.  Here are the lines I'm specifically interested in:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

php_value date.timezone America/New_York
```

I noticed the [PEAR File_HtAccess](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.filesystem.file-htaccess.php) package, but it seems to only address authentication portions of the `.htaccess` file.

---

**SOLUTION:** (with credit due to [Bamieater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618764/parsing-an-htaccess-file-with-php/3618846#3618846))

`echo` statements for debug output, removed from working code.

```
$htaccess = file(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/.htaccess');
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($htaccess as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^\s*SetEnv\s+APPLICATION_ENV\s+(.*?)\s*$/', trim($line), $matches)) {
        defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV', $matches[1]);
        echo APPLICATION_ENV . PHP_EOL;
    } elseif (preg_match('/^\s*php_(?:admin_)?value\s+date\.timezone\s+(.*?)\s*$/', $line, $matches)) {
        date_default_timezone_set($matches[1]);
        echo date_default_timezone_get() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Hmmm. Aren't Apache's configuration files pretty straightforward to parse manually? Everything is `name value` and ignore lines starting with `#`.

Comment: are you using linux:ubuntu or windows

Comment: @Pekka - That's true, but I thought there may be a snippet already written
@JapanPro - It's Linux. CentOS, I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the .htaccess file per line and use a regular expression to access the data.

For example something like this:

```
$line = "php_value date.timezone America/New_York";
$pattern = "@^php_value date.timezone (.*)$@";

if(preg_match($pattern,$line,$matches))
{
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: Just an addition: I'd use `/^\s*php_(?:admin_)?value`..., just that little bit more robustness.

Comment: @Wrikken - I understand the `\s*` part, but what does `(?:admin_)?` accomplish?

Comment: Found the answer. `php_admin_value` settings set the same values, but cannot be overridden. `?:` at the beginning of a subpattern prevents it's matches from being captured.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing a bit from Bamieater, here's a more complete function you can drop into the beginning of your cron job file that sets the environment variables and includes the php_prepend_file.

```
function isCLI() {
    return (PHP_SAPI == 'cli');
}

function loadEnvironmentFromHtaccess($file) {
    $line = file_get_contents($file);

    $pattern = '@SetEnv (?P<env>[^ ]*) (?P<value>[^ \n]*)@';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $_SERVER[$match['env']] = $match['value'];
    }

    $pattern = '@php_value auto_prepend_file (?P<value>[^ \n]*)@';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches)) {
        require $matches['value'];
    }
}

if (isCLI()) {
    loadEnvironmentFromHtaccess(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../.htaccess');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing `.htaccess`, despite it is easy to do, is not the best solution in my opinion.

The environment variable may be set in different places, so you'd have to check all the files (eg. main Apache configuration, other .htaccesses).

I'd recommend setting separate environment variable for your shell scripts,

```
export APPLICATION_ENV=staging
```

I keep those settings in global properties of the server (apache config and .bashrc), so automatically all the apps know where they are without changing the files upon deployment.

Comment: I agree with your opinion, but in my case I don't have control over the Apache environment, nor do I have command-line access, so this one `.htaccess` file is the only place that this environment variable is set. My solution works for me, but may not be optimal for others.

Comment: Agreed. I assumed if you can write command line script, you may also export an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer but it might interest you (or others that come into this thread).

I wrote a little `.htaccess` parser, in PHP, that enables one to manipulate the file as an ArrayObject.

You can check the project [**here (GitHub)**](https://github.com/tivie/php-htaccess-parser).